# Flash AS 3 Loader OnComplete Inside a Loop

Tags: loops, actionscript-3, events, flash, loader

As a followup to the question, *[How to get associated URLRequest from Event.COMPLETE fired by URLLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338317/how-to-get-associated-urlrequest-from-event-complete-fired-by-urlloader)*, how can I make the function work for loader object in a loop?

Here is my existing (rough) code; I always get the mylabel from the last element of the array.

```
var _loader = new Loader(); 
for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    //mylabel variable is correct setup in the loop
    _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void {
        doneLoad(e, mylabel);
    });

    _loader.load(new URLRequest(encodeURI(recAC[j].url)));

}//for loop
```

Comment: Your code as is attempts to assign the EventHandler for the onComplete event 5 times.  Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do?  Your array is not being referenced here... just a looping bit of code that executes 5 times.  I think a bit more of your code needs to be visible for suggestions to be made.  You also are not letting your initial loader complete anything - by calling _loader.load() on the same object over and over again, you are effectively canceling the previous load request.

Comment: You might want to put the declaration of var _loader = new Loader(); WITHIN the for loop - that way you will have 5 loader objects created instead of trying to use one for all 5 objects. There seems to be some confusion here about how event listeners function - again, a little more detail would help.

Comment: Thanks! Iam trying to assign dynamic 'Image()' objects byte data from remote images. I am also passing on values of 'mylabel' which are assigned fron a recAC array to a label field.
I think basically, if you can tell me as to who to repurpose the  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338317/how-to-get-associated-urlrequest-from-event-complete-fired-by-urlloader
so that it works for a 'loader' object then that will be big help. Specifically, the line:
  xmlURLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(req:URLRequest):Function {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments above, this won't work because:

1) You're just adding the same event listener 5 times to the loader.
2) You're just reseting your same loader object 5 times.

The final output will just be as though you only called it the last time.

There are a variety of ways to address this - loading stuff asynchronously is one of the great mindfucks of learning to code - but the simplest way is probably just to create five separate loaders.

I'd do something like this:

```
var loaders:Array = [];
var labels:Array = ["label1", "label2", "label3", "label4", "label5"];
for (var j:int = 0; j < 5; j++) {
loaders[j] = new Loader();
loaders[j].contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
loaders[j].load(new URLRequest(encodeURI(recAC[j].url)));
}

function completeHandler(e:Event):void {
doneLoad(e.currentTarget, labels[loaders.indexOf(e.currentTarget)]);
}
```

The confusing part is finding a good way to keep track of which load is associated with which label etc, since in theory your loads can finish in any order. That's why I've got a separate label array there, and then you just match up the desired label with the loader that just finished loading.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, I think I am close! But this expression is not being resolved, according to Flex debugger:
labels[loaders.indexOf(e.currentTarget)]);

Comment: Hmm, it should be... Arrays have the indexOf() method which returns the index of the item you're passing in, if it is in the array. Not sure what would cause that not to work? There are other ways to address this - you could use a dictionary instance, for instance. in your loop, dict[loaders[j]] = labels[j] then in your handler just something like: doneLoad(e.currentTarget, dict[e.currentTarget])

A million ways to solve it, but it sounds like you're close. Just play with it. :)

Comment: Yes, the 'loaders' array does have a bunch of 'loader' objects but the matching should be exact in case indexOf()

Comment: I think I have fixed the problem using your solution but with slight modification! The e.currentTarget was returning the 'url' of the image whose bytes were being returned from the server.
doneLoad(e, labels[urls.indexOf(e.currentTarget.url)]);
simply creating a new 'urls' array and populating it with urls within the loop did the job. I told ya I was close!
Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

the line belove should work but it returns -1, always.
loaders.indexOf(e.currentTarget);

Here my code

for(i; i < total; i++){
        imgLoaderArray[i] = new Loader();
        imgLoaderArray[i].contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, urlError);
        imgLoaderArray[i].contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
        imgLoaderArray[i].load(new URLRequest(xmlList[i].image));
}

function loaded(e:Event):void{ 
    trace("index: "+imgLoaderArray.indexOf(e.currentTarget)); // return -1 every time
}